# Connect Python to MS SQL Server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pyodbc, pymssql

I am having a problem connecting pyodbc to my SQL Server.  When I run it, there is no output at all and there is not error message or anything to tell me what is wrong? Even after I hit enter a few times nothing?

```
 import pyodbc
 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=marketing-sql01.onlive.corp;DATABASE=grok;UID=austin.trombley;PWD=XXXX')
 cursor = cnxn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("select * from user")
 rows = cursor.fetchall()
 for row in rows:
      print row.user_id, row.user_name
```

Comment: are there any rows in the user table?

Comment: Yes there are 5,000+ rows in the user table

Comment: Did you run through debugger and step through? Did it just exit with no errors or is it stuck some where in wait mode?

Comment: as an aside, can you replace `pyodbc` with `pypyodbc` and see if you have better luck?

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
...

for row in rows:
    print row['user_id'], row['user_name']
```

Comment: pyodbc [row values](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Rows) are accessed by either column name (`row.column`) or integer (not string) indices (`row[0]`).

Comment: Ah, I guess my answer is only valid for Postgres.

Comment: This is pyodbc behavior, regardless of the database management system.